# Did a Subaru "Main Fuse Panel Flaw" Exist?

Tags: electrical, subaru, factory-flaws

At one point I read where someone stated an issue with Subaru Main Fuse Panels. The information was unchallenged, and numerous accounts of conjecture were provided by assumingly individual users of the forum where the information was presented, which seemed to further support that the flaw was present.

It seemingly effected Subaru universally; effecting all models, and platforms, for Early-00's-Late-10's MY's. The issue was regarding the main fuse panel and/or main positive terminal at the panel being a factory flaw. Excessive corrosion would cause all manner of electrical gremlins.

It was considered a major cause of the common headlight bulb failures, among other common issues.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: how can corrosion be a factory flaw?

Comment: Where was this? Jackanory or a verifiable source?? This topic was about fairly recently...

Comment: @Moab Essentially because it was effecting new(er) vehicles. Also if I remember correctly that the corrosion was occurring inside the fuse panel, where it should not occur.  The point of the question is that I read this, committed it to memory, and now I can't find any example of it anywhere. I can't answer questions, because I literally don't know anything about it. I realize that isn't very conducive to finding an answer, but I am utilizing SE in hopes that someone else saw what I saw, and understands what I am getting at. This is a question, I am not claiming that a flaw existed.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know the answer. I assume that not seeing any insults or arguments against it, and seeing numerous accounts of issues being resolved through replacement of the panel, implies that it was relatively factual in someway, but that's pretty much the entire point of my query is to find out if it did indeed exist as a flaw.

Comment: Best place to check wiuld be a subaru forum : they would know, however if one exists I don’t know : there is a volvo forum, jaguar forum ... but subaru ???

Comment: Looked for subaru+fuse on here which gave nothing (except your post) so don’t hold your hopes up...

Comment: I work on a lot of subarus and have never encountered this issue.

Comment: Must be a Subaru urban legend....

Comment: One thing to consider is a poorly maintained battery, acid can leach up the inside of the battery cables into the fuse box.